# Injection current with ADC

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, adc, injection-current

I am using this [Controller](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18F26-45-46-Q10-Data-Sheet-40001996E.pdf) & I see that the clamp current mentioned on page 706 is 20mA per IO pin.

I was not able to find any value that would indicate the maximum allowable clamp current for the entire IC or a group of pins. If that's not there, then its safe to assume that each pin can handle a injection current of 20mA right?

Also, is this 20mA injection current same for the internal ADC peripheral?

Comment: Note that the clamp current is specified for Vpin outside the rails (<0 or >supply). So it is more than likely the current through the clamp diodes (eg Fig15-1 on p224). So the clamp current will only apply if the voltage is outside the rails and being conducted by the protection diodes. Also note that p706 is talking about absolute maximum ratings. According to p706, these are absolute maximum ratings. Perhaps some indication on how you're proposing to use this chip might help.

Comment: "this document is locked and can only be read by entering the correct password"

Comment: @user85471, thank you. at any case, irrespective of the peripheral pins, the current should not exceed 20mA, right?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18F26-45-46-Q10-Data-Sheet-40001996E.pdf

Comment: Same problem. I downloaded it from Mouser https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/PIC18F26_46_56Q43_Data_Sheet_40002171E-2449384.pdf

Comment: What can also happen (and I have seen) is that the current through the clamp diodes can affect the supply voltage. Eg if current through the top clamp diode has nowhere else to go, it will raise it, possibly taking it out of spec. So in some cases, 20mA clamp current (which sounds fine) could have subsequent effects that causes other specs to go beyond their absolute maximum. IE the pin can handle it but other things may not.

Comment: thank you @user85471, what about the injection current on the ADC pins? What effect will it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safe assumption is that it's one pin at a time only.

That is an **absolute maximum** rating, which means you should **not** expect reliability or normal operation under those conditions. It's a limit which, if exceeded, may cause immediate permanent damage to the chip. You might consider it a once in a decade lightning event that the chip would survive and be expected to function properly again (perhaps only after the power is cycled).

I know from experience that causing the protection networks to conduct can have unexpected effects on nearby pins, for example, particularly noticeable on ADC inputs.

In general you should avoid applying voltages more than 300mV outside the supply rails when you expect normal operation of the chip. Perhaps even less than that if your operating junction temperature range includes very high temperatures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the 20mA, is for per pin at a time, right? There's value relating to the group of pins or total pins, right? Also, what happens if there injection current into the ADC peripheral?

Comment: All the datasheet guarantees is that the chip will survive (but not necessarily work properly during the injection) if you don't do it too often or for too long (not defined). In practice, current tends to leak out into other pins, and for too-high currents the chip can latch and be destroyed very quickly (depending on the power supply). There can also be slower damage that occurs over time from current paths that are not intended (due to high internal current densities). That could change by chip or with revisions so no guarantees.

Comment: Thank you. From where you got the value of 300mV in your answer?

Comment: It's frequently specified as the recommended limit for CMOS ICs. A silicon diode junction will not conduct much current when forward biased at 300mV even at high temperature.

Comment: So, if my voltage rail is 3.3V, and I apply an input of 5V on the IC, then the resistor value would be (5V-3V)/0.02A = 100ohms, right? The 0.3V drop is for the internal ESD clamping diode internal to the pin, right?

Comment: @Newbie:  You should not apply 5 volts to any pin if the supply voltage to the chip is 3.3 volts.  The chip is not guaranteed to operate correctly at the voltages and currents listed in the Absolute Maximum Ratings table.

Comment: No, don't do that (unless the specific pin is stated to be '5V tolerant', and even then you have to be careful since it's sometimes not 5V tolerant with Vcc=0).  Just don't *ever* apply voltages  outside the chip supply rails (even with Vcc = 0) and you'll be fine. If you need to convert 5V logic levels to 3.3V or back there are plenty of logic level converter chips that will do a fine and reliable job of doing that.

Comment: FYI, I would read that as 20mA for any individual pin (implied: in any combination +/-), so long as total pin currents are honored, and power dissipation. I agree it's probably a good idea not to push very many pins at once.  As an **abs max** rating, it is indeed not a functional rating, only a no-damage rating.

Comment: @TimWilliams I suspect it's somewhere in between, but not safe to assume. Reading datasheets optimistically frequently leads to tears.  Or as one American author put it, you'll "visit Sorrow's kitchen and lick out all the pots".